# In Eureka, what is the plasma/smoke screensaver they use?

Tags: props, sy-fy, eureka

I noticed in *Eureka* season 3, episode 16 "You Don't Know Jack", that in the background setting of the locked-down lab, there is a type of multi-colored display of swirling plasma/smoke. I was wondering if anyone knows what this actually is, if its a screensaver I can download, or if it has a name - scientifically or artistically?

The design is really cool and I would like to get something similar for myself and would just like some information on it or things resembling it.

I assume it is a prop and not just a green-screen effect. Here is the closest visual I could find:

[image: A frame of the show with the swirly-smoky screensaver visible.]

Comment: custom made most likely.

Comment: Really Slick Screensavers (http://www.reallyslick.com/screensavers.html) has some that look vaguely similar.

Comment: It is very blurry but it seems to be in the range of  [electricsheep](http://electricsheep.org/)

Comment: I am pretty sure it isnt electricsheep, beacuse of way of the movement (yes I have seen the episode).

Comment: I haven't seen the series, but that picture looks like the [Northern Lights](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aurora_%28astronomy%29) to me

Answer (score 1):

The one I found is not quite the same, but it looks like an aurora borealis. For Windows 7, you can [get it here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/7221-aurora-screen-saver-restore.html).

And it [looks like this](http://www.sevenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/8216d1239856840-aurora-screen-saver-restore-aurora_example.jpg).